# Need help multithreading SQL processing

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm processing a SQL table, but it has over 20,000 rows so it is taking forever.

So I was thinking about having a thread manager: Send 10-20 threads to process the SQL results and then after they complete send 10 more. I have a column in the DB to indicate if the table has been processed.

I'm using Sequel and no Rails.

Comment: It doesn't sound like threading is going to help. You need to look into data loading for that many entries.

Comment: There is no way to create 10 threads that will use the same method? For example: `10 threads executing ProcessDB(id)` ?

Comment: Creating the threads is not the problem, I was commenting on the strategy. The bottleneck is the database server not the application. I seriously doubt running that using threads is really going to speed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can create 10 threads in ruby and wait for them to complete:

```
threads = []
0..10.times do 
  threads << Thread.new do
    processDb()
  end
end
threads.each { |t| t.join } # wait for thread to finish
```

Comment: I will start implementation on this ASAP. I will vote as the answer if all goes well. You have been more than helpful and I appreciate your time greatly.